# PHP GoogleCalendarAPI FreeBusy

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I got error in Laravel:

```
Class 'Google_FreeBusyRequest' not found
```

But I added code at the begin controller:

```
use Google_FreeBusyRequest;
use Google_FreeBusyRequestItem;
```

Got errors for both classes.

Before this class all working:

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__.'client_secret.json');
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2calendar');
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setAccessToken($access);

    $calendar_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $freebusy_req = new Google_FreeBusyRequest();//crash
    $freebusy_req->setTimeMin(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime("2017-02-21 08:00:00")));
    $freebusy_req->setTimeMax(date(DateTime::ATOM, strtotime("2017-02-21 23:00:00")));
    $item = new Google_FreeBusyRequestItem();//crash
    $item->setId('primary');
    $freebusy_req->setItems(array($item));
    $query = $calendar_service->freebusy->query($freebusy_req);


    dd($query);
```

WHY?

Comment: try Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequest.  helps to just check the file https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for the help! It works

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$client = $this->getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$freebusy_req = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequest();
$freebusy_req->setTimeMin(date(DateTime::ATOM,strtotime('2022/01/28')));
$freebusy_req->setTimeMax(date(DateTime::ATOM,strtotime('2022/01/29')));
$freebusy_req->setTimeZone('Europe/Madrid');
$item = new Google_Service_Calendar_FreeBusyRequestItem();
$item->setId(*your_calendar_id*);
$freebusy_req->setItems(array($item));
$query = $service->freebusy->query($freebusy_req);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain what your code does. It would help the community much more that way to learn from you!